# Changing Activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This gallery Activity is working fine.i need following Activity as a fragment.i tried to change activity to fragment but slide is  not working.so someone help me to change

```
public class Cast_Activity extends Activity {

    private ViewFlipper myViewFlipper;
    private float initialXPoint;
    int[] image = {  R.drawable.istill_16,R.drawable.istill_15,
            R.drawable.istill_13,R.drawable.istill_14,
            R.drawable.istill_12,R.drawable.istill_11,
            R.drawable.istill_9,R.drawable.istill_10, };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slide_show);
    myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myflipper);

    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Cast_Activity.this);
        imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
        myViewFlipper.addView(imageView);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialXPoint = event.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalx = event.getX();
        if (initialXPoint > finalx) {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == image.length)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showNext();
        } else {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my fragment after i changed

```
public class Cast_Activity extends Fragment {

    private ViewFlipper myViewFlipper;
    private float initialXPoint;
    int[] image = {  R.drawable.istill_16,R.drawable.istill_15,
            R.drawable.istill_13,R.drawable.istill_14,
            R.drawable.istill_12,R.drawable.istill_11,
            R.drawable.istill_9,R.drawable.istill_10, };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_show, container, false);
    myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) ll.findViewById(R.id.myflipper);

    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
        myViewFlipper.addView(imageView);
    }
    return ll;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialXPoint = event.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalx = event.getX();
        if (initialXPoint > finalx) {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == image.length)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showNext();
        } else {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

updated code

```
public class Cast_Activity extends Fragment {


    private ViewFlipper myViewFlipper;
    private float initialXPoint;
    int[] image = {  R.drawable.istill_16,R.drawable.istill_15,
            R.drawable.istill_13,R.drawable.istill_14,
            R.drawable.istill_12,R.drawable.istill_11,
            R.drawable.istill_9,R.drawable.istill_10, };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_show, container, false);
       myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) v.findViewById(R.id.myflipper);

   for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
       imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
       myViewFlipper.addView(imageView);
   }
   return v;
   }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialXPoint = event.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalx = event.getX();
        if (initialXPoint > finalx) {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == image.length)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showNext();
        } else {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer

```
myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) v.findViewById(R.id.myflipper);

       myViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {

           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               OnTouchListener(event);
               return true;
           }


      });


   for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
       imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
       myViewFlipper.addView(imageView);
        }

   return v;

   }

    public boolean OnTouchListener(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialXPoint = event.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalx = event.getX();
        if (initialXPoint > finalx) {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == image.length)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showNext();


        } else {
            if (myViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;
            myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_show, container, false);
myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) ll.findViewById(R.id.myflipper);
```

to

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_show, container, false);
myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)v.findViewById(R.id.myflipper);
```

and `return v;` at the end of `onCreateView(...)`

### Corrected Code:

```
  @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_show, container, false);
    myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) v.findViewById(R.id.myflipper);

for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
    myViewFlipper.addView(imageView);
}
return v;
}
```

Comment: @VibinRejiY For that you need to set `onTouchListener` to your `View Flipper`.

Comment: what for? `LinearLayout` is a subclass of `View` and he is returning it(`ll`) at the end of onCreateView ...

Comment: @Selvin That is wrong. that's why i suggested this changed.

Comment: @Selvin Then how's OP finding `LinearLayout`?

Comment: he is inflating it from slide_show.xml , prolly root of this layout is LinearLayout ... so changing this code has no added vaule at all

Comment: @Selvin Ok. i got it. Then what is the problem with my solution. This solution also working fine...

Comment: you solution is ok(even it is more clear, since there is no need to cast and OP doesn't use `ll` variable as `LinearLayout`) ... but also it has no significant matter here ...

Comment: @VibinRejiY Also apply my second comment..Dude

Comment: @Selvin Ya i got it. But i am just trying to solve OP's problem.That's it. And if you don't like my answer then i will delete it.

Comment: @M D how to set onTouchListener to your View Flipper?

Answer (score 0):

> Do necessary changes to work touch listener to your layout change

```
public class Cast_Activity extends Fragment {
```

> to

```
public class Cast_Activity extends Fragment implement android.view.View.OnTouchListener{
....
onActivityCreated(){
  myViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```